# Проблема с ActionBar

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbar

Скрываю таким способом ActionBar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
```

После этого он исчезает,но приложение перестает корректно работать ,суть приложения - WebView,да пара локальных страниц ничего сложного,приложение загружается,дальше после клика,черный экран,хотя если не скрывать ActionBar Все прекрасно работает

Comment: Создайте чистый проект. Убедитесь что в нём всё работает. Ищите ошибку там, где вы нам не сказали.

Comment: я создал,проблема та же,черный фон и с webView не работает

Comment: Звучит невероятно... Выложите ваш неработающий чистый проект на gitBub - посмотрю у себя. Но прежде пара вопросов - студия новая, второй версии? Не работает на устройстве или в предпросмоторщике?